# dll having method returning a class

Tags: c++, dll

How could I create a method in dll written in c++ which returns a class, and how could I use that dll in java?

If i am export that class the name of that class get changed. Could any body help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to export the class (definition) or do you want to return an object?

Answer (score 2):

You can't export a C++ class from a DLL and use it from a different compiler. What you can, and should, do is to export a COM object.

Comment: You also can't return a class from a C++ function, period. But he probably meant an object.

Comment: I didn't say "return a class from a C++ function". I said "export a C++ class from a DLL". But your point is very valid. I was ignoring the loose terminology.

Comment: I know you didn't say. But the OP did. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You could use JNI, but that's pretty horrible, and you'll have to write the code to convert from a C++ object to a corresponding Java object.

You could also look at JNA, which tries to make this a little easier.